# Is "By the end of today" to mean" synonymous with "by the end of the day"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Is it correct to say "By the end of today", and if so, is it synonymous with "by the end of the day"?

---

I don't see many results  for "By the end of today" on Google, which is casting doubts in my mind.

78 results for "By the end of today":

[image]

vs. 756,000,000 results for "By the end of today"

[image]

---

A similar question was posted on https://english.stackexchange.com/q/217534/17712 by [Abdennour TOUMI](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/44491/abdennour-toumi) but it was [closed](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15017/17712) and the only existing answer doesn't sound definitive.

Comment: Numbers of search results on Google have nothing to do with whether a phrase is grammatical or commonly used correctly.

Comment: @ColleenV it has something to do but indeed it is not in itself sufficient to prove grammaticality.

Comment: 'Today' seems to refer to the *date* but 'the day' could be the *working* day.

Comment: Apparently, Google was in a bad mood when you asked - it yielded `About 81.100.000 results (0,36 seconds)` for me...

Comment: @AndrewTobilko  wow :-/ no idea why. -> [Why does the number of results in Google can sometimes drastically depends on the browser? (e.g., 61,800,000 results vs 78 results)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/154957/18147) Good thing Colleen said it doesn't matter.

Comment: @ColleenV Thanks for saying that. I was getting raked over the coals elsewhere re Google search results.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with it; it's just not how it is usually worded. If you said it in conversation, you would be understood. "By the end of the day" and just "today" are more common.

"By the end of the day" lets you choose which day you are talking about:

> I need this by the end of the day Friday.

means you need it at some point Friday.

> I need this by the end of the day.

means you need it by the end of *this* day (today).

You could also say:

> I need this today.

"By the end of today" is just a little bit redundant.

Comment: People say either one, and they mean the same thing, all other things being equal.